# JavaScript Associative array

Tags: javascript, arrays, oop

I am trying to pass a key-value array. I am using an object literal to construct my slider object, seen below.

```
var test1 = new Slider({set: ['value': 10, 'min': 0, 'max': 20,]});
```

But I cant seem to pass this associate array, it says `:` is an unexpected token. I can only pass a basic array like below.

```
set: [10, 0, 20,]
```

How do I correctly pass the associate array.

Thanks

Comment: javascript does not have an associative array

Comment: @Evert In javascript all objects are associative arrays. He simply has a syntax error.

Comment: @Esailija: associative array is more than an unordered list of properties!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You used the wrong kind of brackets:

```
var test1 = new Slider({set: {'value': 10, 'min': 0, 'max': 20 }});
```

`[]` for an `Array`, `{}` for an `Object`.

Comment: Great thanks :), I thought arrays could be used to achieve the same thing but I must have been wrong :)